# How do I log current state of array post click evevt

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am making a basic tile game. Upon click, I trigger a forEach loop to update the current Array and then compare it to the winning array for the win condition. The winning array is immutable and the current array is represents the the innerHTML of the parent div's with children, if child doesn't exist, the value is null.

I've tried moving the click handler into the forEach loop, I've tried using the index parameter, and I've tried sticking a new for loop ouside the forEach to if I could get the current patten after the click and loop.

```
let winningArrayPattern = ['0', '1', '2', null];`  
let currentArrayPattern = [];

const classSquares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
```

// children`in a NodeList

`const idParents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');` // NodeList

// i have the values, now to map them to parent indexes

```
$('.square').click(function () { 
    currentArrayPattern = [];
    idParents.forEach(function(item,index){

  if (item.children.length === 1){
   console.log(item.children[0].innerHTML, index);`
   currentArrayPattern[index]= item.children[0].innerHTML;`
   } else {
   currentArrayPattern[index] = null;
       console.log('parent is empty', index);
  }
    }); // forEach
   console.log(currentArrayPattern, winningArrayPattern);
  });  // click`
```

I'm stuck, the end result should be at the index of the winning array, correspond that to the current value of what's in that parent div at that location

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DevGru6/yvctwoo5/)

[codepen](http://codepen.io/super996/pen/vyQyxN)

Answer (score 0):

After some help, we discovered that the click event handler that i had above the forEach loop was incorrect. The solution was to remove that click event set the rest of the block in a function and then call that function in the $(document).ready function at the top of my jsfile.

My understanding is that as javascript is getting parsed, it read the click handler above the forEach loop first, then when the document was ready, it sees that click event handler. So, it read the second one first, because the DOM wasn't fully loaded yet. Here is the updated code:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DevGru6/yvctwoo5/3/)

```
$('document').ready(function () {
```

$('.square').click(function () {

```
const parent = $(this).parent('div');
//console.log(this);
$(this).appendTo('.empty');
$('.empty').addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
parent.addClass('empty').removeClass('full');
checkWin();
```

});
});